# JAVA - Printing a random integer from an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating a program in Eclipse and I'm currently trying to get a random integer that's stored in an array to print out. I think I'm nearly there, but instead of printing one of the numbers at random, it's printing a number based on how many numbers in the array there are. So {23, 24, 25} is printing either 0, 1 or 2 (I think). I'd like it to pick one of the stored numbers. I've got

Computer Class:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Computer {

int [] compAge = {19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31};

Computer (int[] compAge)
{
    this.compAge = compAge;
}

int age = new Random().nextInt(compAge.length);
}
```

And in my Main class I've got:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainConversation {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
Computer comp1 = new Computer(null);

System.out.println("Random value of array : " + comp1.age);

}
}
```

I've only started using Arrays this week, and I can get this to work if all the code is within the MainConversation class, but I'd like to have them separate.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: didn't you already ask this question?

Comment: `comp1.age` is index, to get element from array use `array[index]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

```
int age = compAge[new Random().nextInt(compAge.length)];
```

This will select a random age from the array.

Comment: That's perfect, I thought I was quite close. Really appreciate the help.